# Gitlab API equivalent to git log (get the commit revision)

Tags: git, gitlab-api

I want to find SHA1 commit in the branch that has lastly modified files in specified directory. For this purpose I can use command like this:

```bash
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H master <directory>
```

Is there any opportunity to do it via Gitlab API on remote repository without cloning it?

Comment: You can use `ls-remote` without cloning. Not GitLab API but avoids the cloning

Comment: @knittl `git ls-remote` doesn't list non-head commits and doesn't allow to filter them by files/directories.

Comment: [List repository commits API call](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/api/commits.md#list-repository-commits) could be filtered by `path`.